# Username Validation

Tags: javascript, html, regex

```
function validate(username) {
    var reg = /^\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;

    if(reg.test(username)) {
        alert("is correct");
        return true;

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include some actual content describing the question.  Examples of username input that is failing that you would expect to succeed would be a good start

Comment: What is the end result you are looking for?

Comment: If you're looking to validate an email address (which your question is NOT clear about), there are thousands of articles and examples of using a regex to check an email address on the web.  No need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: what is the pattern of the username, in words?

Comment: Since there is Zero description of exactly what you're trying to accomplish and what patterns you want to accept and what patterns you want to reject, this question needs to be closed or put on hold soon (not enough info describing your problem) if you don't clarify what you're trying to do.  It looks like you are new here, but when you post, you must include enough information for someone to understand and answer your question and after posting, you should watch the comments that arrive in the first 10 minutes and clarify your question if people are asking questions because they are confused.

Answer (score 2):

### Pattern requires an `@`

This pattern `^\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*$` requires an `@` in your input.

It matches `a@a` but not `someusername`.

If you want to build a username regex, I suggest you can with something simple like:

```
^[-.\w]{2,20}$
```

and tweak from there.

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `[-.\w]` matches one word character (letters, digits, underscores), dash or period
- `{2,20}` matches two to 20 of these characters
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: _username_ is a variable. _username_ may hold "a@a" .

Comment: @MAKZ Yes, I realize that. It sounds like he wants to match something that looks like a username. If he tries against `someusername`, it will fail.